# Linking between tables in different spreadsheets in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I wonder if it's possible to link tables from different spreadsheets.

I have several live projects running at the same time, for each I have a "Project finance" sheet, in which I have different tabs (Labour cost, Material cost, Project summary).

I would like to create a SUMMARY sheet with all my project, where I can link/mirror copy the project summary tables from all my projects. This needs to be "live", i.e. as we make changes in the project finance sheets (as the projects progress), on this summary table it would update automatically.

In Google sheet this is the formula I would use, but I only recently started using Numbers and I couldn't find anything similar in there.

```
=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/138XdwtZoMVsdMwJOzT4R8Zzg2NNc9pxTV-ARDPvHoj8/edit#gid=63426406","Customer finance!A1:N100")
```

You can basically create a "live carbon copy" this way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference every table on every sheet by name/title, as long as they are within the same document.

(In the screenshot below, there is a table "Material Cost" in the sheet "Material Cost" with some values in column B that add up to 15.)

[image]

Comment: Does it mean you can not reference tables from different documents at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, exactly this.